# Как изменить значения в реестре Windows

Tags: python, реестр

Я пишу программу которая должна изменять значения в реестре win 10, но ничего не меняется, я использую модуль `winreg`.
Помогите

```
import winreg

keyValue = 'Software\\SAMP'

key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER , keyValue)
winreg.SetValue(key , 'PlayerName' , winreg.REG_SZ , "Simon")

winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

Comment: а можно вопрос? ЗАЧЕМ?

Comment: В лаунчере нужно будет менять ник игрока!

Comment: Нужно или крестик снять или штаны надеть. Т.е. ставить или  r или экранирование.

Comment: не помогает , ничего не меняеться

Comment: Эммм для такой задачи лучше подходит JSON

Comment: а на чистом python как это сделать?

Comment: @Lofectr., а как json помог бы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import winreg

keyValue = 'Software\\SAMP'

key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyValue)
winreg.SetValue(key, 'PlayerName', winreg.REG_SZ, "Simon")

winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

Код работает, только мне пришлось в `Software` создать раздел `SAMP`, иначе в `key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER , keyValue)` возникала ошибка:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Реестр после запуска скрипта выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если нужно записать подполе:

```
import winreg

keyValue = 'Software\\SAMP'
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyValue)
winreg.SetValue(key, 'PlayerName', winreg.REG_SZ, "Simon")
winreg.CloseKey(key)

keyValue = 'Software\\SAMP\\PlayerName'
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyValue, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'Name', None, winreg.REG_SZ, "SimonSimon")

winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А вот так выглядит создание раздела `SAMP` и всего что в нем:

```
import winreg

key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software')
winreg.CreateKey(key, 'SAMP')
winreg.CloseKey(key)

key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\\SAMP')
winreg.SetValue(key, 'PlayerName', winreg.REG_SZ, "Simon")
winreg.CloseKey(key)

keyValue = 'Software\\SAMP\\PlayerName'
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyValue, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'Name', None, winreg.REG_SZ, "SimonSimon")

winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот две функции для чтения и записи ключа.
И пример использования.

```
import winreg as _winreg

REG_PATH = r"SOFTWARE\my_program\Settings"

def set_reg(name, value):
    try:
        _winreg.CreateKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH)
        registry_key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0, 
                                       _winreg.KEY_WRITE)
        _winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, _winreg.REG_SZ, value)
        _winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return True
    except WindowsError:
        return False

def get_reg(name):
    try:
        registry_key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0,
                                       _winreg.KEY_READ)
        value, regtype = _winreg.QueryValueEx(registry_key, name)
        _winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return value
    except WindowsError:
        return None


set_reg("mysetting", '100')

print(get_reg("mysetting"))
```